# Creating a documentation app with Cordova and Hugo?

Tags: android, cordova, hugo

I am building a documentation site with [Hugo](https://gohugo.io) and [Docdock](http://docdock.netlify.com). That part is working without issue.

I've then attempted to wrap the site with [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) to build an app. Building the browser app works except that the search dropdown doesn't show up.

However, when I build the Android app, the CSS and JS aren't properly linked. And when I attempt to click on the links in the app, I get errors along the lines of "File not found: file:///srd/feats/climbing". How do I get a multi-page website to be properly wrapped by Cordova so the links and functionality all works?

I haven't seen anything obvious in the Cordova docs.

Comment: you gotta show up the code or load the project in github for others to help you out. With out posting code, the error trace simply makes no sense